# obtener acceso a la camara navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de obtener acceso a la camara web mediante navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia pero cuando resuelvo la promesa siempre obtengo el mismo error:

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous)

Como podría resolver este problema.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```js
let permission = document.querySelector("#start");

permission.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var camera_permission = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video:true,
        audio: false
    }).then((stream)=>{
      if(stream.active == true){
        console.log("la camara esta activa")
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Comment: quieres grabar o hacer fotos?

Comment: Es una aplicación que graba vídeo (para mostrar al usuario) y gif  con RecordRTC.js al tiempo y envía el gif a giphy y después lo trae y lo muestra, estaba funcionando bien, pero hoy me mostró ese error en el then, y no he podido saber que es hasta el momento

Comment: A veces funciona en edge pero no en firefox  ni en chrome. no se si sea problema de giphy que esta respondiendo muy lento ultimamente

Comment: Sospecho que segun lo que acabas de decir el problema no es el codigo.

Comment: igual no sirve en chrome ni en firefox